# Start HSQLDB database manager on application startup?

Tags: java, spring, hsqldb

Is it possible to start the HSQLDB Database manager automatically somehow when I´m working in my local dev environment? I´m using the in-memory DB at the moment. I found some code to start the database manager when running test cases. Can this be used when starting a web application as well?

```
org.hsqldb.util.DatabaseManagerSwing.main(new String[] { "--url","jdbc:hsqldb:mem:moviecollection", "--noexit" });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am assuming you are using Spring because you tagged your question with it. You could create a Spring bean that has a method that is annotated with the [JSR-250 annotation](http://www.infoq.com/articles/spring-2.5-part-1) `@PostConstruct`. Method annotated with `@PostConstruct` indicates that the method should be invoked after the bean has been created and dependency injection is complete.

```
@Component
public class Initializer
{
    @PostConstruct
    public void init()
    {
       org.hsqldb.util.DatabaseManagerSwing.main(new String[] { "--url","jdbc:hsqldb:mem:moviecollection", "--noexit" }); 
    }
}
```

If you would start the `DatabaseManagerSwing` with a web application it would get created and displayed on the server your WAR is running on which you probably don't want to do.

Answer (score 0):

You did not need to start it explicite. It is enougth if you configure the connection url and add the jars.

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
  <property name="driverClassName" value="org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver"/>
  <property name="url" value="jdbc:hsqldb:mem:demo"/>
  <property name="username" value="sa"/>
  <property name="password" value=""/>      <
</bean>
```

Comment: Hmm, maybe I was a bit unclear. I´m not asking how to initiate the database itself, I´ve done that already. I want to know how to start the database manager so that I can browse my tables etc.

Comment: Why don't you just create a script that will execute the manager whenever you want? (opsystem startup, or include the launch of your IDE in the script, etc)

Answer (score 0):

if you use maven try [exec java program](http://mojo.codehaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/examples/example-exec-for-java-programs.html), bind it to the *deploy* goal

i am sure there are similiar solutions for ant based projects